# Organizing rows based on values from three columns

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, sorting, group-by

Imports and getting the dataset

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'DaysExperienceTask': ['7', '8', '2', '6', '9', '3'],
               'TaskType': ['Informatica', 'Spotfire', 'Python', 'Spotfire', 'Informatica', 'Powerbi'],
               'User': ['Vaughad', 'Kodams', 'Sreddy', 'Kodams', 'Vaughad', 'Sreddy']})
print(df)

  DaysExperienceTask     TaskType     User
0                  7  Informatica  Vaughad
1                  8     Spotfire   Kodams
2                  2       Python   Sreddy
3                  6     Spotfire   Kodams
4                  9  Informatica  Vaughad
5                  3      Powerbi   Sreddy
```

This is the result I would like to get

```
  DaysExperienceTask     TaskType     User  TaskCount
0                  7  Informatica  Vaughad     16
1                  8     Spotfire   Kodams     14
2                  2       Python   Sreddy      2
3                  6     Spotfire   Kodams     14
4                  9  Informatica  Vaughad     16
5                  3      Powerbi   Sreddy      3
```

I would like to sum the 'DaysExperienceTask' by each 'TaskType' and make

sure it corresponds to the correct 'User' and is then displayed in a new column 'TaskCount'. This should tell me how much Experience a User has with each task.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: `df.groupby(['TaskType', 'User']).sum()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas group-by and sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39922986/pandas-group-by-and-sum)

Comment: @user3483203 When I do that I get '79' instead of 16 for what is supposed to be 7+9

Comment: Sounds like you have a column of strings for `DaysExperienceTask`.  Try `df['DaysExperienceTask'] = df['DaysExperienceTask'].astype(int)` before you try the groupby

Comment: @user3483203 you've been a great help. Would you have any idea how to add the total for each DaysExperienceTask and put it into a new column like I have done in the question?

Comment: Yes, in that case you want to use `df['TaskCount'] = df.groupby(['TaskType', 'User']).transform('sum')`

Comment: @user3483203 You're the best, Thank you very much I have been stuck for some time.